# I deleted my light

Tags: light

I accidentally deleted my light. Now I can't get it back. I tried adding one of the other light options, but it doesn't seem to cast the same kind of light. I also can't seem to find one that says "Light".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The light in the default scene is a point light named "Light". It has the following properties:

- Location: $(4.0762, 1.0055,  5.9039)$
- Power: $1000\ W$
- Radius: $0.1\ m$

[image: Default point light properties]

A new point light can be added through the menus *Add > Light > Point*. If you set the same properties for the newly created point light it should look just like before.

[image: Add point light]

In general, if you've made a mistake you can undo changes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> or through *Edit > Undo* in Blender's header / top bar.

Comment: Much Thank you, my friend!

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.